# Isomorphism between graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-isomorphism

Are the graphs G1 and G2 isomorphic?
[image]

I think that the graphs are not isomorphic because G2 has a cycle tuwzt, where all vertices have deegree 4. No such cycle can be found in G1. Therefore because isomorphism preserves cycles G1 and G2 can’t be isomorphic. Is that correct?
/Erika

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Looks right to me.